# Qt: performing an action (scroll) after a widget has been added

Tags: qt, user-interface

I have a horizontal scroll area and dynamically added widgets inside it.

I want it to scroll to the very end whenever a new widget is added, so that the user sees the last widget using this method:

```
void scrollToEnd()
{
    scroll->horizontalScrollBar()->setValue(100000);
}

...

layout->addWidget(widget);
scrollToEnd();
```

However, there's a delay between calling `layout->addWidget()` and actual widget appearing. So calling `scrollToEnd()` does nothing.

If I make apause by, for example, showing a MessageBox, everything works fine.

Is there a way to wait till the widget is displayed, and then scroll the scroll area?

Comment: there is showEvent ( QShowEvent * event ) method in QWidget, this might help you

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But strangely there's still a delay...

Comment: You say you are using a horizontal scroll area.  Is it a QScrollArea?

Comment: Have you tried using QScrollArea::ensureWidgetVisible()?

Comment: `ensureWidgetVisible` doesn't work either...

Answer (score 0):

`addWidget` probably schedules the actual addition of the widget to after the reentering of the event loop, so you should do the same and call the `scrollToEnd` method asynchronously (it has to be a slot):

```
layout->addWidget(widget);
QTimer::singleShot(0, this, SLOT(scrollToEnd()));
```